# No ADB driver for medion e4001 (MD 98500) for remote debugging

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

For testing purposes I need to debug an older android device:
`MEDION LIFE e4001 (MD 98500)`

There are no drivers available online and I wrote to the MEDIUM guys receiving the following answer:

> Thanks for your feedback. We are gladly share the following information with you: There are currently no plans to develop debug drivers for the  Medion smartphone e4001. If you want to transfer data they are not necessary - when connected to a pc the phone will appear as a usb storage device.

So no official ADB driver for that device. Is there any chance to get a working ADB driver for that device somehow?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks for sharing your knowledge by answering your own question!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (for windows):

1. Download the [official MEDION ADB driver](http://www.medion.com/de/service/_lightbox/treiber_details.php?did=10773) for some other tablets they offer
2. Unpack
3. Open the `android_winusb.inf` file in a [texteditor](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.9.1.html)
4. Add the following lines at the end of the two sections `[Google.NTx86]up` and `[Google.NTamd64]`
5. `;
   ;MEDION Life E4001
   %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_109B&PID_911E
   %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_109B&PID_911E&MI_01`
6. Go to the device manager, select the unknown driver (called generic in my case), update driver and select the folder.

Off you go!